# When using Xcode 14 with Firebase the Syntax Highlighting is not working. Some Syntax Highlighting works but most Firebase related code is not white

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I have been looking for a while but haven't found a solution yet. Xcode 14.2 Syntax Highlighting is not working correctly. Is anyone else experiencing this issue? Does any know how to fix this issue?

Here is an example image below. `Firebase.Config()` is white. All tutorials I have watched the syntax highlight works thought out. This is just one example, but for the most part, very few Firebase SDK related code has any Syntax Highlighting.

[image]

(I tried finding answers to this issue, but so far haven't found anything recent which discusses this issue.)

Comment: Usually when I've noticed syntax highlighting not working for some package, it's because the package hasn't been built yet, or I haven't added it as a dependency to my target - in which case the `import` shows an error.  But your description doesn't sound like that's what's happening.  Have you tried cleaning the build folder (cmd-shift-K) and rebuilding?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.